# unable to load xml data into IE browser

Tags: html, cross-browser

i am using the below code from w3schools to load xml data into my html page.BUt its working in mozilla browser only, no other browser is giving any output...Please check the code for the necessary changes to be made

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
 xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
 ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
 xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
 resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the `cdcatalog.xml` and `cdcatalog.xsl` files available

Comment: Do you get any errors, check Developer Tools

Comment: @Musa : Error showing on the line xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);  as access is denied

Comment: Are you running this on a webserver? If you are running it from filesystem that might be your problem.

Comment: yes now changed to webserver now its giving error as GET http://localhost:8080/xml-project/xml/cdcatalog.xml 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost:8080/xml-project/xml/cdcatalog.xsl 404 (Not Found)....I put both xml and xsl file under WEB-INF, Do I need to specify any path or need to write any action to load the same

Comment: If you don't supply a path the files need to be in the same directory as the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line

```
xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

instead of

```
 xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

it works